# Changing a list item dynamically in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is a bit of a mess, but I've been trying - literally - all day so I am a little bit frazzled.

I'm trying to do something that would take me 20 seconds in JQuery, but in React 
 ¯_(ツ)_/¯

Essentially, in my application, tags have an importance associated to them (1-9). Great stuff.

I have a list group that returns my tags in importance order:

```
const TagScreen = ({
    tags
  }) =>
{

 return(
   <ListGroup>
    { tags.sort(function(a,b) {return a.importance < b.importance}).map((tag) =>
      ( <span key={tag.id}>
          <ListGroupItem className='taglist' bsStyle="success"><p>{tag.name}</p>
              <ListItem 
                active={tag.importance} />
          </ListGroupItem>
        </span>
      )
    )}
   </ListGroup>
 )

}
```

The ListItem is a (very) poorly named component (so much refactoring to come when I've got this working) but it's essentially an importance selector. It looks like this:

```
const ListItem = ({index, active}) =>
  { 
    var rows = [];
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    var style = '';
    if (active === i) { style = "active" }
      rows.push(<li className={style}><a href='#'>{i}</a></li>)
    }

  return( 

      <ul className="pagination pull-right pagination-sm"> 
        { rows.map((row) => row)}
      </ul> 

    )
  }
```

Again, I'm sure this is terrible, I am a React Newbie. Essentially, all I want is for the 'active' style (which starts at the current importance of the tag) on the pagination element to change to the one clicked. I've tried so, so much to do this. I'll deal with the actual pinging of the server and changing the importance of the tag later, once I've got this damn style to change onClick.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I don't really see the `onClick` statement in your code, which component is your container component? Where is your data coming from at the time? So with which state should your listItem negotiate the new state?

Comment: Do you want each list item to change its style independently or do you want each list item to be able to change the style of the group?

Comment: I updated my answer with a more detailed explanation, hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to make sure you have a state to save your changes to, so you need a container component that either contains the state, or use something like redux to handle the state for you to your container props

After that you could do it like this

```js
const RangeSelector = ({min, max, current, onSelected}) => {
  let items = [];
  for (let i = min; i < max; i++) {
    items.push(<li className={i === current && 'active'} onClick={(...args) => onSelected(i, ...args)}>{i}</li>);
  }
  return <ul>{ items }</ul>;
};

const Tag = props => {
  return <div>
    <h2>{ props.title }<small> ({ props.importance })</small></h2>
    <RangeSelector current={ props.importance } min={1} max={11} onSelected={ (...args) => props.onUpdate( props.id, ...args ) } />
  </div>;
};

class TagContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      tags: [
        { id: 0, title: 'C#', importance: 5 },
        { id: 1, title: 'JavaScript', importance: 1 }
      ] };
  }
  updateTag(id, value) {
    this.setState( this.state.tags.reduce( (current, item) => {
      if (item.id === id) {
        item.importance = value;
      }
      current.push( item );
      return current;
    }, [] ) );
  }
  render() {
    return <div>
      <h1>Tags</h1>
      <div className="tag-list">
      { this.state.tags.map( (tag, key) => <Tag onUpdate={(...args) => this.updateTag(...args)} key={tag.id} {...tag} /> ) }
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <TagContainer />, document.querySelector('#app') );
```

```css
.active { background-color: green; color: white; }
ul { list-style-type: none; display: inline-block; }
ul li { clear: none; display: inline-block; padding: 5px; }
ul li:hover { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

So the detail of the little application above would be the following:

- 1 container component, named `TagContainer`

it holds the state to the tags, and updates its state when a child component gets changed. It starts with an initial state, which you can see in the constructor:

```
constructor(...args) {
  super(...args);
  this.state = {
    tags: [
      { id: 0, title: 'C#', importance: 5 },
      { id: 1, title: 'JavaScript', importance: 1 }
    ] };
}
```

This means, I will have 2 tags, one with C# and one with JavaScript, starting with an importance of respectively 5 and 1

During the rendering of the container component, it renders a stateless component, named `Tag` and it inserts an update function over it's props, which you can see here:

```
<Tag onUpdate={(...args) => this.updateTag(...args)} key={tag.id} {...tag} />
```

This indicates, that when `onUpdate` gets called, it will forward the update to the `this.updateTag()` function, which will update the state. All arguments that were send will be forwarded to the function as well. The arrow function makes sure that the context of `this` refers to the current TagContainer instance.

Updating the state is done through the `this.setState()` function, where you send the updated state, so that React can rerender the container component.

Now this might look overly complicated, and it probably is, but it will recreate the tags array in the state, and update the one state that is meant to change

```
this.setState( this.state.tags.reduce( (current, item) => {
  if (item.id === id) {
    item.importance = value;
  }
  current.push( item );
  return current;
}, [] ) );
```

The `id` and the `value` are passed in through the 2 stateless components, defined above.

- 2 stateless components, `RangeSelector` and `Tag`

`RangeSelector` is responsible only for showing the available values in a certain range, and setting the active class on the element that is currently selected. When it gets clicked, it will send the value through the `onSelected` method it received through it props from the `Tag` component

The `Tag` component is responsible of showing the current tag, and renders the title and the `RangeSelector`. It receives an `onUpdate` method from the `TagContainer` component, and when it gets called by the `RangeSelector` it adds 1 extra argument and forwards it to the `TagContainer` component.

In the end, the state gets changed, and react will re-render your application, leading to an update of the DOM (as there are differences between the virtual dom and the real DOM)

Comment: Thanks so much for this incredibly detailed response! I need to pick through it before I make it the answer but I will do as soon as I understand it!

Comment: Again, thanks for this. A couple of questions: I come from a RoR background, and having this much "stuff" going on in the front end is crazy to me - is this normal in React? Is there never a performance issue?

One other question - when do you just use a const, and when do you use the extends React.Component pattern? I thought it was just a matter of taste, but it seems like you have used it for the bigger component, or a component that has functions within it, is that right?

Comment: @PaulHarker Yeah, it's not only a matter of taste. Presentational components like the Tag & the RangeSelector do not need the more complex setup, they are only worried in doing something with the props they are given, the container components are laying out those presentational components and manage the state. Other than that, it can also depend on which framework you use behind it to manage the state (eg: redux or mobx). I do not think React is overly complicated, it's a way of creating components that can standalone, and could be reusable. It tries to reduce complexity, not add :)